# Why should I use "the" instead of "this" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, articles, pronouns

I posted a question here a few hours ago. The title of the question is

`What does 'sus' mean in this sentence "People who joined Facebook after 2017 are sus."?`

Later, a community bot modified the word `this` to `the`.

[image]

I am a bit confused. Why should I choose "the" instead of "the"? I tried to search for answers but sometimes it's very clear, like "the bus" vs "this bus", but in this case, I'm really confused.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I can't see any improvement in "the" over "this".  Both are fine.

Comment: @JamesK thanks. since it's a community bot so I am afraid I made any mistake.

Comment: The community bot edit means that "This edit was suggested by an anonymous user".  They are often lower quality edits, since they are not from users with reputation on the site.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for the updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question; the difference is subtle.
Your original question was perfectly understandable, but it was corrected because it's not completely grammatical.  I think I understand the reason, but it's possible I am wrong.

"this sentence" is a complete noun phrase, and would require a relative pronoun after it if you want to add something, like "...in this sentence *that reads* 'People who joined Facebook..." but you just stuck a separate sentence right after it with no connecting word.

"the sentence, 'People who joined Facebook..." is a valid noun phrase by itself, though.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence you used was correct and understandable.  The word "this" is a piece of discourse deixis that refers to the quoted sentence. You should have used a colon before the quote. That would set the quote off as a separate sentence.

There's no mistake in using "the", but little improvement.